# Mange Event > Configure > Dithered Options

Tags: civievent

I am attempting to send emails to participants that are registered for events.  When I access **Manage Events** and select **Configure** - the option for **Schedule Reminders** is dithered out and not sure why.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Dither Image on Manage Event > Configure]

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue that happens with the Shoreditch theme. It is due to a problem between Core and Shoreditch/Bootstrap, that I've [written about here.](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2542)
You can still click the top option and then use the top tabs to navigate to the page you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's not disabled - dithered out means that part of the event has not been configured yet. You can go ahead and click it.

Comment: It is disabled in Shoreditch

Comment: Ah ok. Didn't know that.

Comment: Is there a way to enable it in Shoreditch?

Comment: Not right now. The problem is that Civicrm adds the disabled css class to the link, which just greys it out in CiviCRM, but in Bootstrap, which Shoreditch uses, this disables the link. I'll work on a solution, but for now, it's just something we have to live with.